# diff: Find files that differ and are in the second directory

Tags: shell-script, diff

Say that I have these files for example:

```
old/common-change/index.html
new/common-change/index.html
new/only-new/index.html
old/only-old/index.html
```

The output of `diff -qr` is close to what I want:

```
$ diff -qr old/ new/
Files old/common-change/index.html and new/common-change/index.html differ
Only in new/: only-new
Only in old/: only-old
```

However, for the ones that are only in `new/`, I want their filenames. Not just the parent directory. I also tried using `diff -qrN`, but then I can't easily filter out the files that are only in `old/`.

```
$ diff -qrN old/ new/
Files old/common-change/index.html and new/common-change/index.html differ
Files old/only-new/index.html and new/only-new/index.html differ
Files old/only-old/index.html and new/only-old/index.html differ
```

Since I want to find the files that differ, but are also included under `new/`. I want to get rid of all the files that are included only in `old/`.

The only files I want to get `diff` output for are:

```
new/common-change/index.html
new/only-new/index.html
```

If it matters, the context is that I want to figure out which pages changed since the last commit in my website repository. I'm building the previous version to `old/` and the current version to `new/`. So I want to run tests on all the pages that changed, but ignore pages that were deleted (since I can't run tests on a page that doesn't exist).

Comment: Can't you use `git status` / `svn status`, or whatever the equivalent is in your version control system to see the differences from the last commit?

Comment: No, because that requires adding two directories that are both about 30 MiB to git. They're the generated files after running Hugo (static site generator). I can't just diff the source files because then there could be changes in files that affect other pages.

Comment: That how about using `.gitignore`?

Comment: If I add the output to .gitignore then I can't use any `git` commands on it (such as `git diff` or `git status`...

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`, you could do something like:

```
zmodload zsh/stat
old=(old/**/*(ND-.)); old=(${old#old/})
new=(new/**/*(ND-.)); new=(${new#new/})

# in new, not in old:
new_files=(${new:|old})

# loop over files common to both sets:
for file (${old:*new}) {
  stat -A old_size +size -- old/$file || continue
  stat -A new_size +size -- new/$file || continue
  # compare size to avoid calling cmp as an optimisation
  (( old_size == new_size )) ||
    cmp -s -- {old,new}/$file ||
    new_files+=($file)
}
```

With the result in `$new_files`, use something like `ls -ld -- new/$^new_files` to pass that list with `new/` prepended to each to `ls`.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the best solution but I figured something out with a chain of pipes:

```bsh
diff -qrN old/ new/ |
    grep -oP '(?<=\s)new\/\S*' |
    xargs -rd '\n' ls -1d 2>/dev/null
```

I would like to know if there's any better way to do this.

Comment: Not that with `-N`, if `file` can't be found in `old` and is found in `new` but empty, it won't be reported.

Comment: Also note that it assumes file path don't contain newline characters nor `\snew/`

Comment: About `-N`, it shouldn't report if the file in `new` is empty, just if it exists in `new` but not in `old`, right? That's what I want, I'll add some extra context to my original question.

Comment: What I mean is that `mkdir old new; touch new/file; diff -qrN old new` outputs nothing even though there's a file in new that is not in old.

Comment: Oh, I guess I need a fix for that then. Glad you caught that.

Comment: Actually, it was a false alarm. It turns out that making an empty file (like with `touch`) is completely ignored. If I do `echo test > new/file` for example, then it works fine, and it says they differ.

Answer (score 0):

One option may be to use `rsync` in dry-run + checksum mode, here storing the result in a bash 4.4+ array, and using `perl` to decode the `\#ooo` sequences rsync uses to encode some byte values:

```
readarray -td '' new_files < <(
    rsync --out-format=%f -rcn new/ old/ |
      perl -p -l0 -e 's/\\#([0-7]{3})/chr(oct($1))/ge'
  )
```

Same in `zsh`, using the `0` parameter expansion flag to split the NUL-delimited list:

```
new_files=(
  ${(0)"$(
    rsync --out-format=%f -rcn new/ old/ |
      perl -p -l0 -e 's/\\#([0-7]{3})/chr(oct($1))/ge'
  )"}
)
```